# Should function arguments be weak?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I have following case with weak reference:

```
function hello(to persons: [Person]) {
    /// should persons be also weak below?
    helloView.didHelloPressed = { [weak self] someFlag in 
        self?.configurePersons(persons)
    }
}
```

In above code, I captured weakly and I understand that `self` should be weak because I use its function (`configurePersons`). But should `persons` array, which is argument of `hello` function be also weak? I think yes, but I don't clearly explain it. I thought that if `self` is not nil, then `persons` also will not be nil and it doesn't make sense to make it weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak references aren't something you should use "just because I see a closure".

Even with closures, and even with `self`, there are *plenty* of times where you don't want a weak reference.

Weak references exist to break strong reference cycles. That's it. The captured variables of closures are one kind of strong reference that exists. If a closure strongly captures a variable, nothing scary happens.

The issue is when a closure captures `foo`, and then you store the closure inside the `foo`. That's a strong reference cycle, which needs to be broken. One of the two references needs to be weak, so either you should hold the closure weakly in the `foo`, or you should capture the `foo` weakly in the clsoure.

Your `persons` has type `Array<Person>`. There *could* be a strong reference cycle if one of those `Person` objects has a strong reference to `helloView`, which itself has a strong reference to its `didHelloPressed` closure. But that would be very weird, and is almost certainly (hopefully!) not what you're doing, so no, there's no need to weakly capture `persons`.

Even more, depending on the relationship between `helloView` and what `self` is in this context, it's entirely possible that you might want to capture self strongly, too.

Comment: `self` in this context is subclass of `UIView`. `helloView` is subview of `self`. So, should `self` be captured strongly and why?

Comment: @neo If I recall correctly, `UIViews` stongly retain their subviews. If `helloView` is strongly held by `self`, `didHelloPressed` was strongly held by `helloView`, and `self` was strongly captured by the `didHelloPressed` closure, then yes, you would have a strong reference  cycle. You can cut it by **1)** making `helloView` weakly referenced by `self` (not possbile, since you don't control the UIKit code that defines `UIView.subviews`, plus, it's an owning relationship, so it makes sense to be strongly refed), **2)** making `helloView` weakly reference the `didHelloPressed` closure, or...

Comment: ... **3)** making `didHelloPressed` weakly capture `self`. #3 is probably the most logical choice. Does that make sense?

Comment: Suppose that inside `configurePersons` function I have one line code that refers to some object(which is class) of `self`. Then, can I write that object inside my capture list instead of writing `self` just to refer to that object later? And what if that object is value type? I shouldn't capture it, should I?

Comment: @neo I don't really know what you're talking about. I need more context.

Comment: Ok, look to `configurePersons` function in my question. Suppose, it is like following: `func configurePersons(_ persons: [Person]) { personsView.configure(persons) }` As you see, `configurePersons` justs delegates this task to `personsView`. As you know, inside my `didHelloPressed` closure, I capture `self` just to call its `configurePersons` which actually delegates this task to `personsView`. So, can I capture weakly `personsView` immediatly and call its `configure` func inside closure, instead of capturing whole `self` just to call `configurePersons` which actually calls `personsView` func.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah, you can do that, what worries you that you couldn't? You don't even need to capture `personsView` weakly, as long as there isn't a strong cycle. You're fine so long as `personsView ` doesn't have a strong ref to `helloView `, otherwise you would get this cycle: `helloView -> didHelloPressed -> personsView  -> helloView `. I think you should write some memory leaks, and spending some time in the memory graph debugger and instruments, to really get a feel for what they are, how they work, and how you can resolve them

Comment: Thanks, but how to figure out is there a strong cycle or not? How do you identify it?

Comment: "spending some time in the memory graph debugger and instruments, to really get a feel for what they are, how they work, and how you can resolve them "

Answer (score 1):

Array is a value type in Swift. It not managed by ARC. So, the answer is No.

Comment: But what if `Person` is class?

Comment: You mean that if array contains reference type, the whole object ([Person]) considered as as value type anyway?

Comment: I mean func doesn't increase retain count. Try to check retain count by `CFGetRetainCount` func.

Comment: Check retain count of what? If you mean `persons`, Xcode doesn't allow me to do this because it is not castable to CFTypeRef

Comment: "It not managed by ARC." welllllllll not quite. It's a struct that contains a reference to a heap allocated buffer, which itself is very much ARC managed.

Comment: Alexander, array, not the items it contains, not managed by ARC isn't it?

Comment: @AleksandrMaybach The buffer storing the array's items (whether they be value types stored inline, or ARCed references to objects of class types) is ARC managed. You should check out the source of `Array` and see for yourself. But think about it this way: if the Array wasn't ARCed, how would CoW work, which relies on `isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)` to know if a copy is necessary or if direct mutation is fine. Also, since arrays have a dynamic size, how could they be stored on the stack (as local variables of value types are)? Passing them would involve copying the entire array every time

Comment: Alexander - Reinstate Monica, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, function parameters are strongly referenced. I am also not sure there’s a way to pass any parameter as a weak reference. In this case, there is no cycle for calling the function `hello(to: person)`. So, the answer is No.